# Convert file (or byte[]) into ascii, then convert that ascii back into the original file

Tags: c#, ascii, streamreader

I'm using an old technology called RTTY to send data (it's basically fancy Morse Code) over radio.

RTTY can only transmit ascii characters

What I want to do is convert a file such as a small `jpg` or something similar into a block of `ascii` text, send the characters over radio, then convert the characters on the remote end back into the original file.

Some help getting started would be great.

I know I need to use `StreamReader` but then how can I convert the `byte[]` into an encoded `ascii` string that I can then 'decode'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know i need to use streamreader but then how can I convert the byte[] into an encoded ascii string that I can then 'decode'

Basically, you want to use a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) conversion. It will inflate the size of the data, but it guarantees that you'll be able to round-trip the original binary data.

Use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) to convert a `byte[]` into a `string`, and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) to do the reverse.

Comment: Thanks, better late than never :D